# Issue on Selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know why this kind of selection is not working for html select options? As it works for other inputs like Radios or checkboxes?

```js
$('#resetlist').click(function() {
  $('input:select[name=tabs]').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Icecream" name="tabs">
  <option value="0">select from the list</option>
  <option value="double">Double Chocolate</option>
  <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
  <option value="strawberry" selected>Strawberry</option>
  <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="resetlist">Reset List</button>
```

Comment: simple use id `$('#Icecream').val("0");` as you did for `resetlist`

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong: `input:select[name=tabs]` works for radio buttons and checkboxes because they are `input`s, but `select` **isn't** an `input`.

Therefore your selector should be `select[name=tabs]` (without the `input`).

```js
$('#resetlist').click(function() {
  $('select[name=tabs]').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Icecream" name="tabs">
  <option value="0">select from the list</option>
  <option value="double">Double Chocolate</option>
  <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
  <option value="strawberry" selected>Strawberry</option>
  <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="resetlist">Reset List</button>
```

Comment: Thanks ᔕᖺᘎᕊ but I thought select also is a way of inputting data into the forms!

Comment: @Suffii it *is* a way to input data! But it just isn't an `input` tag, it is a `select` tag :)

Answer (score 1):

Selector `input:select[name=tabs]` was wrong.

```js
$('#resetlist').click(function() {
  $('select[name=tabs]').val(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Icecream" name="tabs">
  <option value="0">select from the list</option>
  <option value="double">Double Chocolate</option>
  <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
  <option value="strawberry" selected>Strawberry</option>
  <option value="caramel">Caramel</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="resetlist">Reset List</button>
```